# Trigger IDoc or web service after creation of purchase requisition

Tags: abap, sap-pi, idoc, sap-xi

I have this integration scenario from ECC to SAP PI 7.0: when a Purchase Requisition is created by the MRP process, the PR data should be sent automatically to other party through a web service or IDoc.

1) What would be the ideal scenario for this integration, I mean IDoc to SOAP, RFC to SOAP, etc.?

2) When the PR is created in ECC, how can it be pushed automatically to SAP XI/PI?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) What would be the ideal scenario for this integration, I mean IDoc to SOAP, RFC to SOAP, etc.?

**Between `ECC` to `PI`:**

You can use `IDOC`s:

- There is a standard ability of resend the data.
- `IDOC` sending is asynchronous.

A simpler way (less customization) would be to use `RFC` call.

- There isn't a standard way of resend the data.
- The call could be synchronous/asynchronous

As response to comment, here are general instructions for `RFC` alternative:

1. Create remote enabled function in `SE37`.
2. import it once to PI.
3. Use it in the mapping.
4. The call from `ECC` is performed with the syntax: `CALL FUNCTION 'your_function_name' DESTINATION 'your_defined_destination'`.

**Between `PI` to external system:**

In `PI` mapping, after data arrived from `RFC` / `IDOC` call the webservice (`SOAP`).

> 2) When the PR is created in ECC, how can it be pushed automatically to SAP XI/PI?

In `ECC`, identify a creation of `PR` from `MRP` through a `BADI` like [this](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3594226). Send `IDOC` / Call the `RFC` inside the BADI you chose.

Comment: Thanks Dorad for your answer. Could you please give arguments to your answer?do you know which RFC i can use for this? and the name of the povider proxy i guess on the receiver side? why not using the idoc fr this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I'm absolutely not expert in the domain, but [googling the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=Trigger+IDoc+or+web+service+after+creation+of+purchase+requisition&oq=Trigger+IDoc+or+web+service+after+creation+of+purchase+requisition) (answers come almost exclusively from [SCN](https://www.sap.com/community.html)) made me think that no IDoc can be automatically generated at creation time. Consequently, the workaround is to:

- Implement a user exit triggered when the purchase requisition is created. Maybe the `MD_*` (`MD_PURREQ_POST`?) BAdIs mentioned by Dorad are sufficient, or maybe the exit `EXIT_SAPLMEREQ_008` of the enhancement `MEREQ001` (via a project in transaction `CMOD`), or maybe the BAdI `ME_PROCESS_REQ_CUST`.
- In this user exit, call the function module `ALE_PR_CREATE` to create the IDoc (message type `PREQCR1`).
- Create an IDoc partner agreement in transaction `WE20` so that the IDoc is sent when it's created, or postponed for later sending (job at regular intervals). The port can be tRFC, XML HTTP, etc.

You can find more details for each step by searching the web.

PS: your other question "what is the ideal scenario" cannot be answered without knowing your exact context, like quantity of PRs created during each MRP process, preferences in your company for technical solutions, near-zero custom development, etc.